# What does "Like anyone, they varied." mean? (from Primer movie script)

Tags: american-english

I'm translating *Primer* to Hebrew subtitles, but I just can't understand how to express this sentence. I'm not sure what it means in its context. Here it is:

> *Meticulous, yes. Methodical. Educated.
>
>   They were these things.
>
>   Nothing extreme. **Like anyone, they varied**.
>
>   There were days of mistakes
>
>   and laziness and infighting.                                                                  And there were days, good days,
>
>   when by anyone's judgment...
>
>   they would have to be considered clever.*

Can anyone please try to explain it to me, or give another sentence with the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like anyone, they were **inconsistent**.

Answer (score 1):

Different forms of like anyone/ any other are usually used as a comparison to show similarity in the actions, behaviors or characteristics of different people or things.
For example:

> Just like any other child, John enjoyed playing outside with his friends.

or

> Just like any other parent, Mary was concerned about her children's safety.

or

> Like any other vacuum, the Xonic MXWRE32 made a lot of noise and scared the cat.

Answer (score 1):

This [website](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/p/primer-script-transcript-shane-carruth.html) claims to be the script.

Given the context *they* are some set of entities that *varied*. I.e, they were not all alike. They differed in some way or ways.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, a more wordy way to phrase it would be, "Just like other people, they had moods that changed from day to day."

Comment: Good catch @stangdon. I've corrected it.